# Spring boot controller not being detected

Tags: spring-boot

Good day. I'm having issues with my `Springboot` app. The `controller` isn't being detected.The `Component scan` is used but it won't detect the controllers.

**Folder structure**

[image]

**Application**

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.jokedata.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.jokedata.repositories")
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.jokeweb.project.controllers"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.jokeweb.project.controllers")
public class JokeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JokeDataApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if request URL or application port is correct or not.